# How to access tkinter from different thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, tkinter

I want my app to listen to an endpoint which receives an index and displays the selected image in tkinter. The variable tkinter_app is always none. The tkinter window appears, so it initializes, but it cannot be accessed in the flask function.

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from flask import Flask, request
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
tkinter_app = None

class TkinterApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.play = True
        self.currIndex = 0
        self.canvas= Canvas(self.win, width=self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), height=self.win.winfo_screenheight())
        self.canvas.pack()
        image1 = Image.open("2.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        image2 = Image.open("3.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        image3 = Image.open("4.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
        image4 = Image.open("5.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
        image5 = Image.open("6.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)
        self.images = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5]
        self.image_container = self.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor="nw",image=self.images[0])
        self.win.mainloop()
    def atIndex(self, index):
        print(index)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_container,image=self.images[index])
def run_tkinter():
    global tkinter_app
    tkinter_app = TkinterApp()

@app.route('/image', methods=['POST'])
def process_image():
    data = request.get_data()
    print(data)
    if tkinter_app is not None:
        tkinter_app.atIndex(data)
        return 'Image processed successfully'
    else:
        return 'Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_tkinter)
    t.start()
    app.run()
```

Comment: the atIndex method of TkinterApp expects an integer index, but in the process_image function of Flask, you are passing it a byte string (data). You can convert the byte string to an integer using int(data).

Comment: main issue of not being able to access the tkinter instance from Flask, this is because Flask and tkinter are running in separate threads. Accessing tkinter from a different thread can cause problems such as deadlock, as tkinter is not thread-safe. To solve this, you can use a thread-safe queue to communicate between the two threads.

Comment: @ma9 So I tried changing process_image() to this:
@app.route('/image', methods=['POST'])
def process_image():
    data = request.get_data()
    print(int(data))
    queue.put(int(data))
    return "finished"
and added a function to the Tkinter class :
def run(self):
        while True:
            index = queue.get()
            self.atIndex(index)
and called it in run_tkinter() like so:
tkinter_app.run() 
but it still doesnt work because run isn't called

Answer (score 0):

Uses a queue to communicate between Flask and tkinter
Can you try this :

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from flask import Flask, request
import threading
import queue

app = Flask(__name__)
tkinter_app = None
queue = queue.Queue()

class TkinterApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.play = True
        self.currIndex = 0
        self.canvas= Canvas(self.win, width=self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), height=self.win.winfo_screenheight())
        self.canvas.pack()
        image1 = Image.open("2.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        image2 = Image.open("3.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
        image3 = Image.open("4.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
        image4 = Image.open("5.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image4)
        image5 = Image.open("6.png").resize((self.win.winfo_screenwidth(), self.win.winfo_screenheight()))
        img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image5)
        self.images = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5]
        self.image_container = self.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor="nw",image=self.images[0])
        self.win.after(100, self.update_image)
        self.win.mainloop()

    def update_image(self):
        try:
            index = queue.get(block=False)
            self.currIndex = index
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.image_container, image=self.images[index])
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        self.win.after(100, self.update_image)

def run_tkinter():
    global tkinter_app
    tkinter_app = TkinterApp()

@app.route('/image', methods=['POST'])
def process_image():
    data = request.get_data()
    index = int(data)
    if tkinter_app is not None:
        queue.put(index)
        return 'Image processed successfully'
    else:
        return 'Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_tkinter)
    t.start()
    app.run()
```